# SVG filters in Firefox/Safari issue

Tags: firefox, svg

I'm having issues with applying feColorMatrix in Firefox and Safari. It works ok in Chrome. My objective is to ease the shadow a bit, which I could do by changing shadow color or its opacity. I went for changing the opacity. In Firefox and Safari, the SVG is ignored altogether after I used the feColorMatrix. Code:

```
<filter  id="AI_Shadow_1" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" >
<feGaussianBlur  in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur>
<feOffset  in="blur" dx="18" dy="18" result="offsetBlurredAlpha"></feOffset>
<feMerge>
    <feMergeNode  in="offsetBlurredAlpha"></feMergeNode>
    <feMergeNode  in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
</feMerge>
<feColorMatrix in="the-shadow" result="color-out" type="matrix"
  values="0 0 0 0   0
          0 0 0 0   0 
          0 0 0 0   0 
          0 0 0 0.2 0"/>
 <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="color-out" mode="normal"/>
</filter>
```

If there's more efficient way to lighten the shadow and works cross-browser, then I'm more than happy to use it.

Cheers!

Comment: That should work, please create a [mcve], although now that I look more closely, where is **the-shadow** defined as an output?

Comment: feMerge should be feMerge result="the-shadow" [although it's not really the shadow - it's the shadow merged with the Source. - you should be putting your feColorMatrix between your offset and your merge and drop the final blend.

Answer (score 0):

feColorMatrix

```
 in="the-shadow"
```

should be

```
 in="blur"
```